# Splitting a vector of values into consecutive segments

Tags: r, dataframe

If I have a vector:

```
vec <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

I want to split it into the following data frame of consecutive segments:

```
x    xend
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
```

I could do it using a loop:

```
df <- NULL
for (i in 1:(length(vec) - 1)) {
  df <- rbind(df, data.frame(x = vec[i], xend = vec[i + 1]))
}
```

But is there a function in base R that does the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```r
vec <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

data.frame(
  x = vec[-length(vec)],
  xend = vec[-1]
)
#>   x xend
#> 1 1    2
#> 2 2    3
#> 3 3    4
#> 4 4    5
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr)

data.frame(x = vec) %>% 
  mutate(xend = lead(x)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(xend))
```